# Dr. Kawashimas not compatible with "NINTENDO Switch Lite", because of missing IR Motion Camera Functionality?

Tags: nintendo-switch-lite, kawashima-brain-training

Popluar shops (at least in German speaking countries) sell a bundle NINTENDO Switch Lite and Dr. Kawashimas.

[image]

According to my research the Lite does not have an IR Motion Camera, which means is not compatible with Dr. Kawashimas. It seems you can buy wireless Joy-Con and pair it with Lite, but at additional costs.

It seems also you can't play Dr. Kawashimas at Big Screen (TV), only in handheld mode.

Do I miss something? Why MediaMarkt is selling this bundle?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this support page (it's in Japanese)](https://support.nintendo.co.jp/app/answers/detail/a_id/36730/%7E/%E3%80%90%E8%84%B3%E3%82%92%E9%8D%9B%E3%81%88%E3%82%8B%E5%A4%A7%E4%BA%BA%E3%81%AEnintendo-switch%E3%83%88%E3%83%AC%E3%83%BC%E3%83%8B%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B0%E3%80%91nintendo-switch-lite%E3%81%A7%E9%81%8A%E3%81%B9%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99%E3%81%8B%EF%BC%9F):

> Nintendo Switch Lite でも遊べます。
>
> ただし、Joy-Conの機能を使った一部のトレーニング（「後出勝負テスト」「指計算」「指体操」「野鳥数え」「旗上げ」「箱数え」）は遊べません。

Which (roughly) translates to:

> It can also be played on Nintendo Switch Lite.
>
> However, some training exercises that use the Joy-Con functionality (「後出勝負テスト」「指計算」「指体操」「野鳥数え」「旗上げ」「箱数え」) cannot be played.

(I didn't translate training's name since I don't know how it's called in English version)

However, as you already said in the OP, you can buy Joy-con and accessories that is able to charge Joy-con (since Nintendo Switch Lite can't charge Joy-con unlike normal Nintendo Switch) such as [Joy-con Charging Grip](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01N33MFPK) and [Joy-con AA Battery Pack](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B06ZZY5SNH).

As for the TV mode, some of the trainings can be played on TV mode, however almost all of trainings requires touch function and/or touch pens to write something in the training, so it's not a good idea to play this game in TV mode (to begin with, though, TV mode is not available on the Nintendo Switch Lite).

I'd recommend buying normal Nintendo Switch if you're planning to play any other game in TV mode. NS Lite doesn't have TV mode function as I said above. Just in case, [source](https://www.nintendo.com/ph/support/switch/playmode/index.html).

Comment: For the trainings names, google translator interprets them as "Late Bird Test", "Finger Calculation", "Finger Gymnastics", "Wild Bird Counting", "Raising the Flag", "Box Counting"

Comment: @Wondercricket While other translations may be correct, but unless there is a meaning I am unaware of, it's probably incorrect with regard to the "Late Bird Test", as the training is aimed at winning/losing the game of rock-paper-scissors by playing a move after the opponent. If "Late Bird Test" means that... English is a hard language for me, I guess.